# How to initiate a sync operation automatically in C# windows app/sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, push-notification, azure-sql-database

I I am developing a windows 8 app in C#/sql server 2008 which will sync tables in server and client(Desktop) using Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1.Somehow the sync is working perfectly.But I would like to know is there any way that this sync operation can be initiated automatically whenever a change is detected in the table either in the client or in the server. Aslo i would like to know is there any push notification available in windows azure sql, so that I can start using it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "But I would like to know is there any way that this sync operation can be initiated automatically whenever a change is detected in the table either in the client or in the server" - isn't that what Replication is?

Comment: Client databases reside in client PC's and server DB in server.Client Db gets updated offline and when it gets online the changes should be merger to and from the server.Could Replication works perfectly.If so can you please provide me a link for finding a best tutorial.